# Angular: Dev tools source files (.ts) don´t showing

Tags: angular, google-chrome, devtools

Since few weeks I can´t see the source files in my Angular app to set breakpoints.

I´m using the right setting in `tsconfig.json`:

```
...
"sourceMap": true,
...
```

Any idea what could be the mistake?

[Source files don´t showing](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EA2wN.png)

Answer (score -1):

You might want to try with Ctrl+O and enter the component name. The list will be displayed.

Comment: That´s the same like CTRL + P but I don´t get my component files. The Dev tools can´t reach the source files. I also don´t can see any component directories.